# Precision, Recall and Correctly Classified Instances

Tags: precision

How to calculate the Precision and Recall for yes, no class:

```
               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.444     0.8        0.5       0.444     0.471      0.522    yes
                 0.2       0.556      0.167     0.2       0.182      0.522    no
Weighted Avg.    0.357     0.713      0.381     0.357     0.367      0.522
```

and Correctly Classified Instances is 35.714%

Data weather with Weka

```
@relation weather

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature real 
@attribute humidity real
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

No.  outlook temperature humidity windy play
1   sunny       85.0    85.0    FALSE   no
2   sunny       80.0    90.0    TRUE    no
3   overcast    83.0    86.0    FALSE   yes
4   rainy       70.0    96.0    FALSE   yes
5   rainy       68.0    80.0    FALSE   yes
6   rainy       65.0    70.0    TRUE    no
7   overcast    64.0    65.0    TRUE    yes
8   sunny       72.0    95.0    FALSE   no
9   sunny       69.0    70.0    FALSE   yes
10  rainy       75.0    80.0    FALSE   yes
11  sunny       75.0    70.0    TRUE    yes
12  overcast    72.0    90.0    TRUE    yes
13  overcast    81.0    75.0    FALSE   yes
14  rainy       71.0    91.0    TRUE    no
```

===========================

=== Run information ===

```
Scheme:weka.classifiers.rules.PART -M 2 -C 0.25 -Q 1
Relation:     weather
Instances:    14
Attributes:   5
              outlook
              temperature
              humidity
              windy
              play
Test mode:10-fold cross-validation

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

PART decision list
------------------

outlook = overcast: yes (4.0)

windy = TRUE: no (4.0/1.0)

outlook = sunny: no (3.0/1.0)

: yes (3.0)

Number of Rules  :  4


Time taken to build model: 0 seconds

=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances           5               35.7143 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         9               64.2857 %
Kappa statistic                         -0.3404
Mean absolute error                      0.5518
Root mean squared error                  0.6935
Relative absolute error                115.875  %
Root relative squared error            140.5649 %
Total Number of Instances               14     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.444     0.8        0.5       0.444     0.471      0.522    yes
                 0.2       0.556      0.167     0.2       0.182      0.522    no
Weighted Avg.    0.357     0.713      0.381     0.357     0.367      0.522

=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 4 5 | a = yes
 4 1 | b = no
```

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the confusion matrix:

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 4 5 | a = yes
 4 1 | b = no
```

The Precision is computed as 4/8, i.e. the number of correctly classified `a` (yes) divided by the number of predicted `a`, while Recall is 4/9, the number of correctly classified `a` (yes) divided by the total number of true `a`. The precision and recall for the other class is the converse.

See the definitions of all those criteria in [one single cheatsheet](http://www.damienfrancois.be/blog/files/modelperfcheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks damienfrancois. How to calculate Correctly Classified Instances is 35.7143 %

Comment: That would be (4+1)/(4+5+4+1). Total of correctly classified (primary diagonal of the confusion matrix) divided by total number of instances (sum of all elements of the matrix)